# Open webview link in another View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

I have a webview and I want to open the urls that I can click in that webview in another ViewController for example to change the navigation bar and add a back button.

This is my current code in objective-c:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        NSString *fullURL = @"https://www.apple.com/";
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
        NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        self.webView.delegate = (id)self;
        [self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];

        UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
        [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(handleRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self.webView.scrollView addSubview:refreshControl];



    }

-(void)handleRefresh:(UIRefreshControl *)refresh {
    NSString *fullURL = @"https://www.apple.com/";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
    [refresh endRefreshing];
}
```

Any solutions?
Thank you!

Comment: To get urls clicked on a webview you should implement the uiwebview delegates and check for link clicked on navigationType in "shouldStartLoadingWith" of course don't forget webView.delegate = self more info : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebviewdelegate/1617945-webview

Comment: @RotemDoron thank you, but any idea how to do that? I already set the webview delegate to self.

Comment: first of all why are you releasing the webview?   self.webView.delegate = nil;

Comment: I already removed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from UIWebview delegate you should use "shouldStartLoadWith" and check navigationType for linkClicked:

```
    func webView(_ webView: UIWebView,
             shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest,
             navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    if navigationType == .linkClicked{
        if let url = URL(string:"YourURLString") {
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url){
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
                return false
            }
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

More info about uiwebview delegates can be found here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebviewdelegate/1617945-webview